# Question about autocorrelation_plot result vs autocorr result

Tags: python, pandas, autocorrelation

I used `autocorrelation_plot` to plot the autocorrelation of a straight line:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dr = pd.date_range(start='1984-01-01', end='1984-12-31')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(dr)), index=dr, columns=["Values"])
autocorrelation_plot(df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Then, I tried using `autocorr()` to calculate the autocorrelation with different lags:

```
for i in range(0,366):
    print(df['Values'].autocorr(lag=i))
```

The output is 1 (or 0.99) for all the lag. But it is clear from the correlogram that the autocorrelation is a curve rather than a straight line fixed at 1.

Did I interpret the correlogram incorrectly or did I use the `autocorr()` function incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

You are using both functions correctly, but... [Autocorrelation_plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#autocorrelation-plot) uses a different way of calculating autocorrelations then [autocorr()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.autocorr.html) does. 
The following two posts explain more about the differences. Unfortunately I don't know which way of calculating is the correct way:

[What's the difference between pandas ACF and statsmodel ACF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038927/whats-the-difference-between-pandas-acf-and-statsmodel-acf)

[Why NUMPY correlate and corrcoef return different values and how to "normalize" a correlate in "full" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639280/why-numpy-correlate-and-corrcoef-return-different-values-and-how-to-normalize)

If you need it, you can get the autocorrelations out of your autocorrelation plot as follows:

```
ax = autocorrelation_plot(df)
ax.lines[5].get_data()[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. From what I can tell, `autocorr()` called `np.corrcoef()` which calculates the pearson correlation, which is different from autocomplete correlation. The implementation of `autocorrelation_plot` is correct. I have submitted [an issue on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24608).