# Normalizing cross-correlation to [-1,1] for different length signals

Tags: matlab, normalization, cross-correlation

I have the following piece of code for calculating the cross-correlation between to signals. Visually, the signals are correlating very well. The signals are of different length but both have a sampling rate of 100Hz. There is a lag between the signals (called timeDiff below).

```
  [acor,lag] = xcorr(signal1,signal2);
  [cor,I] = max(abs(acor));
  lagDiff = lag(I);
  timeDiff = lagDiff/100;
  fprintf('Correlation = %0.5f \n',cor);
```

I'm getting a correlation of 6239.06131. How can I normalize this to -1 and 1? Because otherwise it is hard to interpret.

Comment: `cor = 6239.06131` is the maximun correlation, and therefore, it corresponds to the normalized value of +1. In general, you can do `acor / cor` to obtain the normalized correlation for any of the values in the `acor` vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the documentation
https://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html

There is the Normalization option on xcorr function

```
[acor,lag] = xcorr(signal1,signal2,'coeff');
```

that "normalizes the sequence so that the autocorrelations at zero lag equal 1". The 'coeff' option only produces a value of 1 or -1 if a given time shift (lag) results in a perfect positive or negative correlation of two series.

Comment: Unfortunately, this option only works when both series have the same lenght which is not the case.

Comment: could the answer of M.Hassan in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145157/matlab-xcorr-1d-cross-correlation-normalisation-issue be helpful?