# Python 1d correlation normalized and unnormalized values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, correlation

Using `np.correlate` function in order to find the best fit of one array on the other.
In ideal input where the match is exact, I would expect a value of 1 to be returned from the normalized correlation in the relevant index (lag).
Also, why does the `np.correlate` function returns the multiplication from end to start as seen in the output below?

Could somebody clarify how to achieve the desired output and why the reverse multiplication in the `np.correlate` function?

Functions Calls:

```
cor = correlation_normalized([3., 4., 4.], [1., 2., 3., 4., 4., 5.])
cor2 = correlation_normalized([1., 2., 3.], [1., 2., 3., 4., 4., 5.])

corr = np.correlate([3., 4., 4.], [1., 2., 3., 4., 4., 5.])
corr2 = np.correlate([1., 2., 3.], [1., 2., 3., 4., 4., 5.])
```

Function:

```
def correlation_normalized(a, v):
    a = (a - np.mean(a)) / (np.std(a) * len(a))
    v = (v - np.mean(v)) / np.std(v)
    return np.correlate(a, v)  # Default is mode="valid"
```

Normalized function source: [Why NUMPY correlate and corrcoef return different values and how to “normalize” a correlate in “full” mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639280/why-numpy-correlate-and-corrcoef-return-different-values-and-how-to-normalize)

Output:

```
cor = [0.1754116  0.35082321 0.52623481 0.52623481]
cor2 = [0.30382181 0.30382181 0.60764362 0.60764362]
corr = [48. 41. 34. 23.]
corr2 = [27. 23. 20. 14.]
```

Expected Output:

```
cor = [value  value 1.0 value]
cor2 = [1.0 value value value]
corr = [23. 34. 41. 48.]
corr2 = [14. 20. 23. 27.]
```